# Vuex - Access State Data then Pass to Action vs Accessing State Data in Action

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have to use data from state in my action but I'm not sure how should I implement it.

```
const state = {
    oOptions: {}
};
```

Should I get `oOptions` from my component then pass to the action?

```
// Access State Data from Component then Pass to Action

computed: mapGetters(['oOptions']),
methods: {
    fetchProducts: function() { 
        this.$store.dispatch('fetchProducts', this.oOptions).then(/*doSomething*/);
    }
}


const actions = {
    async fetchProducts({ commit }, oOptions) {
        oOptions
        // commit()
    }
}
```

Or just access `oOptions` from the action?

```
// Accessing State Data in Action

const actions = {
    async fetchProducts({ state, commit }) {
        state.oOptions
        // commit()
    }
}
```

Comment: It really depends on the requirements for your application regarding scalability, flexibility and maintainability. Each one has its advantages and disadvantages. Depending on case one can be better suited than the other, but none is wrong, *per-se*.. First allows DRY-er code and is better suited for large scale apps. Second allows more flexibility but complicates writing unit tests. However, your question is *off-topic* on this website for encouraging opinionated answers.

Comment: To find the answer for your case, ask yourself: what's the fastest route towards getting the task done? Who needs to understand the code and when? In which way will the application grow? When it does, what allows modification(s) with less effort/time?